# Convolution of the fundamental solution of the heat equation

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Let $$F(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{4kt}}$$ be the fundamental solution to the heat equation and observe $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x-y,t) dx=1$$ for arbitary $y$.
Next, assume that $\phi(x)$ satisfies $$\vert \phi(x_1)-\phi(x_2)\vert \leq e^{\vert x_1\vert + \vert x_2 \vert}\vert x_1-x_2 \vert$$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to show that $$u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x-y,t)\phi(y)dy$$ is a solution to the wave equation $$\begin{cases}u_t-ku_{xx}=0 \\ u(x,0)=\phi(x)\end{cases}$$
Here is my approach to show $u(x,0)=\phi(x)$:

> Since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x-y,t) dx=1$ for arbitary $y$, we have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x-y,t)(\phi(y)-\phi(x))dy=u(x,t)-\phi(x)$$ Let $\xi=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{4kt}}\Leftrightarrow y=x-\xi\sqrt{4kt}$. Then $$\vert u(x,t)-\phi(x) \vert =\left\vert \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\xi^2}(\phi(x-\xi\sqrt{4kt})-\phi(x))d\xi \right\vert$$ $$\leq \left\vert \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\xi^2}\vert \phi(x-\xi\sqrt{4kt}-\phi(x)\vert d\xi \right\vert$$ $$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\xi^2}\vert \phi(x-\xi\sqrt{4kt}-\phi(x)\vert d\xi $$ $$ \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\xi^2}e^{\vert x \vert+\vert x-\xi\sqrt{4kt}\vert}\sqrt{4kt}\vert \xi \vert d\xi$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt{4kt}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert \xi \vert e^{-\xi^2}e^{\vert x \vert+\vert x-\xi\sqrt{4kt}\vert} d\xi$$ $$ \leq \frac{\sqrt{4kt}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert \xi \vert e^{-\xi^2}e^{2\vert x \vert}e^{\vert\xi\sqrt{4kt}\vert} d\xi$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt{4kt}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{2\vert x \vert}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert \xi \vert e^{-\xi^2+2\vert \xi \vert \sqrt{kt}}d\xi$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt{4kt}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{2\vert x \vert}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert \xi \vert e^{-(\xi-\sqrt{kt})^2+kt}d\xi$$ $$=\frac{e^{kt}\sqrt{4kt}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{2\vert x \vert}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert \xi \vert e^{-(\xi-\sqrt{kt})^2}d\xi$$
> Let $\eta=\xi-\sqrt{kt}$. Then $$\vert u(x,t)-\phi(x) \vert \leq \frac{e^{kt}\sqrt{4kt}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{2\vert x \vert}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert \eta + \sqrt{kt} \vert e^{-\eta^2}d\eta $$ $$ \leq \frac{e^{kt}\sqrt{4kt}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{2\vert x \vert} \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert \eta \vert e^{-\eta^2}d\eta + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert \sqrt{kt} \vert e^{-\eta^2}d\eta\right)$$ $$=\frac{e^{kt}\sqrt{4kt}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{2\vert x \vert} (1+\sqrt{\pi kt})$$
> by the Gaussian integral. Therefore, $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0+} \vert u(x,t)-\phi(x)\vert \leq \lim_{t \rightarrow 0+}\frac{e^{kt}\sqrt{4kt}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{2\vert x \vert} (1+\sqrt{\pi kt})=0$$

I am curious about two parts:

1. Does my approach have no error? Is there any shorter proof?
2. Is it okay to say $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0+}\frac{e^{kt}\sqrt{4kt}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{2\vert x \vert} (1+\sqrt{\pi kt})=0$ for arbitrary $x$? I think $x$ increases faster than $\sqrt{4kt}$ decreases.

Could you give me any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you mean heat equation?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, it is another name.

Comment: As @peek-a-boo says, it's _heat_equation_, and it's _not_ the same as the wave equation, ... it is qualitatively hugely different. Please do edit...

Comment: @paulgarrett Sorry! I confused it with my another question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1. What you show is that the solution $u(x,t)$ starts at $\phi(x)$ which is what we expect. Please don't ask someone to check your work. 2. Why should this not be OK ? Why does $x$ increase as $t$ tends to zero?

Comment: @KurtG. 1. I asked that because the proof when $\phi$ is Lipschitz continuous is much shorter and more elegant. I thought there would be another way to take the 'generous' boundary. 2. If we assume $\phi$ is Lipschitz continuous, we can bound $\vert u(x,t)-\phi(x)\vert$ solely by the terms of $t$. I am curious about what happens if we choose $x$ arbitrarily large, typically $x > O(\ln t)$, so that RHS of the inequality diverges.

Comment: Don't get it. You are proving that $\lim_{t\to 0+}|u(x,t)-\phi(x)|=0$ for every fixed $x$. Why we care at this point how fast $x$ increases?